# Adding new WebMethod to WebService won't show on publishing it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have this problem with WebServices on C#, the thing is that when I add a new method to the WebService, after compiling it, it doesn't show this on the running WebPage, neither on the WSDL. Has anybody had this problem too? I've been trying to make it work all day long, all ready tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding, also checked that the method has de label [WebMethod] and yes, they are public methods, I don't know what else could be the problem.

**EDIT** The webservices are made using asmx

Comment: OK, just to be clear...  You add a method, public, with the [WebMethod] block just before the method declaration, then copy it out to your server so it's at `http://yourserver.com/possiblyasubpath/yourservice.asmx`  Then when you navigate to that page, you refresh it, and the method isn't showing up on that page. Is that what your'e saying?

Comment: Yes, thats right, but before doing it I recompile it so the .dll's will update

Comment: @DarthVader I have it in a .cs file, the .asmx references to it

Comment: OK.  Good question. It sounds like you're doing everything right.  Can you provide a code sample, and possibly a screenshot of how the .asmx page looks?  Remove anything sensitive, of course....  We don't need actual code inside the method, you could cut it out, take a screenshot, and paste it back in...

Comment: @DavidStratton
This is how the .cs looks like, basically all of the methods are the same `[WebMethod]
        public ObjectResponse GetObject()
        {
            ServiceAdapter sa = GetServiceAdapter();
            return sa.GetObject();
        }`
and this is for the .asmx
`<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service.asmx.cs" Class="SOA.Host.Service" %>`

Comment: @DavidStratton the image of how the .asmx looks like on the WebBrowser is downwards, therefore, it updates on my partner computer, but on my, where I need to check that everything works, doesn't show anything of the new thing I add

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the answers of:

[Additional method in webservice not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339955/additional-method-in-webservice-not-showing-up?rq=1)

the problem might come from an asmx markup file that was copied across that didn't update its namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you don't have WebMethod declared as `static` (C#) or `shared` (VB) and be sure that you have `[WebMethod]` (C#) or `<WebMethod()>` (VB)